# Make virtual tour from photos

Tags: software

I have been presented with an option to make a virtual tour for my school. Kind of like a Google's Street View but for a school building. It should be made so that everyone on the school's webpage can click on it and take a virtual tour of the school.

I am looking for a software that can do that and that is compatible with websites after exporting the tour if it's managed that way. The best would be a free software, if not, what are the best ones?

Any suggestions and precautions I should take before making such a virtual tour?

Thank you!

Comment: It's not a duplicate because in that thread they are talking about 1 and single cube or virtual photo. What I am trying to discover here is about how to merge more virtual photos into a collection which then will act as an entire tour. A person can be able to move from class to class, from room to room.

Comment: It's the same, except for with an area which you can click which leads you to the next set.

Comment: The two packages I mention under the "Delivery Format" section of my answer on the "duplicate" can also do virtual tour hyperlinking. There aren't many free options, I've only been able to google one donationware package, [JATC](http://www.panoclub.de/jatc/).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for assembling a set of photos into a panoramic image or VR image, [Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/) is a great and free tool.

For navigable tours, you have many options. You need to convert the stitched images into cube image maps with a software, create navigation links, and then view the assembled tours. Look around [this link](http://wiki.panotools.org/Panorama_Viewers) to find the tool and output format you prefer.